# How to iterate 2 list along with modification through java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have multiple classes but i want to set object through map.

```
    Class A1 {
    private String inventoryOwner;
    private String sourceKey;
    private String source;
    /*Getter-Setter*/
    }
```

Another class B1

```
    Class B1 implements Iterable<A1>{
        private final Collection<A1> b1 = new ArrayList<>();
     public void add(A1 a1) {
            b1.add(a1);
        }
    
        public void addAll(Collection<B1> b1) {
            this.b1.addAll(b1);
        }
    }
```

Another class C1

```
     Class C1 {
     private String locale;
      private B1 sources;
    
    public B1 getSources() {
            return sources;
        }
    
        public void setSources(B1 sources) {
            this.sources = sources;
        }
        /*getter and setter functions*/
    }
```

Collections are as follows:

```
    Map<String,List<A1>> mapOfA1 = new HashMap<>();
List<A1> listOfA1 = new ArrayList<>();
A1 a1 = new A1();
a1.setInventoryOwner("abc");
a1.setSourceKey("dummySourceKey");
a1.setSource("dummySource");
listOfA1.add(a1);

mapOfA1.put("abc",listOfA1);

A1 a2 = new A1();
a2.setInventoryOwner("abc");
a2.setSourceKey("dummySourceKey");
a2.setSource("dummySource");

List<A1> listOfA2 = new ArrayList<>();
listOfA2.add(a2);

B1 b12 =new B12();
b12.addAll(listOfA2);

C1 c1 = new C1();
c1.setLocale("en-us");
c1.setSources(b12);
    List<C1> listOfC1 = new ArrayList<>();
listOfC1.add(c1);
```

size of listOfA1 and listOfC1 is same.

I want to set value of mapOfA1 in b1 like b1.addAll(mapOfA1.getValue()) but during iteration it is setting only last list values.

```
 listOfC1.forEach(inventoryConfig -> {
                // second loop for filtered elements
                mapOfA1.entrySet().stream().filter(it -> (it.getValue().size()!=0)).forEach(ec -> {
                    B1 b1 = new B1();
                    b1.addAll(ec.getValue());
                    inventoryConfig.setSources(b1);
                });
            });
```

It is setting last value of Map, not sure how to make it workable.

Comment: You say “size of listOfA1 and listOfC1 is same” but in your code, there is no `listOfA1` at all. There are two lists of `C1` and a single `A1` object. Your attempted solution is using entirely different names, `C1` (uppercase) and `map`. Even when we try to map them to `c1` (lowercase) and `mapOfA1`, there are two entirely unused variables in your input, `listOfC1` and `a1`.

Comment: sorry @Holger, I have edited the question.

Comment: Did you forget to put `listOfA2` into `mapOfA1`? When `mapOfA1` has multiple entries, how are they supposed to map to the single `listOfC1`? What is supposed to happen to `a1`, `a2`, and `c1` in your example? And when all lists are supposed to have the same size, why does your solution attempt have this `filter(it -> (it.getValue().size()!=0))`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding `b1` to `inventoryConfig` again and again which overrides previous values.
I would recommend keeping `B1 b1 = new B1();` above `map.entrySet().stream()` and `inventoryConfig.setSources(b1)` after it.

Something like:

```
 B1 b1 = new B1();
 map.entrySet().stream().filter(it -> (it.getValue().size()!=0)).forEach(ec -> { 
     b1.addAll(ec.getValue());
            });
  inventoryConfig.setSources(b1);
```